# I want to load a large HTML page with a lot of redundancy as fast as possible. What is the best way?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to load a very large HTML page containing nothing but the letter 'x' (let's say 10000 lines of each 100 characters), each of the characters linking to a similar url: the first one to www.example.com/1, the second to www.example.com/2, etc.

Of course I cannot just generate the entire page with php because it would build a very large file for the browser to download. But if I try it with javascript and a simple for-loop, it takes ages for the script to complete.

Any solutions for this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a fantastic design... :)

Comment: what? im not sure what u want to do....

Comment: I've *got* to know why you need this. Please tell us.

Comment: you want to display something without the overhead of displaying something?

Comment: Turn on gzip compression at the server. You've so much redundancy that it'll compress extremely well.

Comment: If you're trying to optimize your JS, you should post your JS

Comment: @byteboy The problem is not quite related to gzip compression or network speed. It is about size of the DOM and time needed to create the DOM, resolve styles and layout of 1,000,000 DOM elements. That is a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much better idea:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    console.log("Clicked at coordinates ", e.pageX, e.pageY);

    // Convert in your own fashion; here's one idea:
    var index = (e.pageX % 100) + (100 * e.pageY);

    window.location.href = "http://example.com/" + index;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are pretty much your only options.  Only thing I think you can do is use a faster browser (test out the latest versions of the current browsers, recent years have seen lots of javascript optimization) and/or a faster computer.

The biggest issue though is why are you doing this?  I can't think of any practical use for this, and most likely there's a better way to do what you're actually trying to accomplish

Even generating it server side, it'll likely take a long time to render.  We've recently tried loading a page that hasn't needed paging previously because the dataset has always been small, but with a huge dataset even though the whole page was transferred, it still froze the entire browser for over 5 minutes before we had to kill the process.  I suspect you'll run into similar issues if it's really that much stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The following chokes for about 20s in FF on my machine, about 6s in Chrome. A good portion of that is spent parsing the injected DOM, and I suspect this would remain the case for a downloaded DOM of the same structure. No matter how you approach this, it's going to foul up the user's browser for a while.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(function() {
        var strings=[];
        for(var a=0;a<10000;a++)
        {
            for(var b=0;b<100;b++)
            {
                var c=a*100+b;
                strings.push(
                    '<a href="http://www.example.com/'+c+'">x</a>');
            }
            strings.push("<br/>");
        }
        var megaString=strings.join("");
        $("body").html(megaString);
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Not that the question is ever going to end up with a practical answer, but wouldn't it be more efficient to call the native createElement instead of having the browser parse html? Or even use `$('<a/>', {href: 'http://www.example.com/' + i.toString(), text: 'x'})`

Comment: @Anthony: spender's doing his DOM parsing all at once, in the `.html()` call, instead of working with native DOM structures the whole time.

Comment: Which appears to be way faster than my (now-deleted) method of using `DocumentFragment`s, hrm.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not very clever. 10,000 times 100 is 1,000,000 elements. The most efficient way is use P elements with a minimal id, then use a click listener on the body element to determine which element was clicked on and genrate the URL. So your html looks something like:

```
<html><title>Silly Page</title>
<style type="text/css">p {display:inline;margin:0;padding:0}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doNav(e) {
  var id = (e.target || e.srcElement).id;
  window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/' + id.replace('p','');
}
</script>
<body onclick="doNav(event)"><p id=p1>x<p id=p2>x<p id=p3>x<p id=p4>x...
</body>
```

If you are trying to associate a link with a location on a page, use an image map, it will be vastly more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. To make a virtual view. In this case you
   will load only visible elements and
   do scrolling/panning manually
   (similar to maps)
2. To output/populate just text
   "xxxxx...." and handle clicks by
   coordinates and synthesizing
   hyperlink clicks by code. In this
   case you will have only one DOM
   element - container of x'es